# Random short freezes in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, freeze

**Configuration**

Motherboard : Gigabyte P55-UD3R
CPU : Intel i7-860 @ 2.8GHz
Memory : Super Talent DDR3-2000 (CL9), DDR3-1600 (CL6) @ 1333 CL8
Harddrives attached to Builtin P55 SATA controllers

**Symptom**

Random freezes that happen especially on disk access. At time of freeze, mouse moves are possible, Keyboard lights can be toggled on and off, but there is no responsive to mouse clicks and keyboard commands (even Ctrl-Alt-Del).

After a while (usually within 1 minute) the command seems to have played back and everything is running smooth as usual.

**Diagnostics ran**

Memtest86+: Several full cycles without problem.
HDD SMART: Diagnostics ran with normal results, no bad blocks.
Graphics card: Running 3D games without problem at high resolutions (e.g. World of warcraft @ 2560x1440x32, not that i played it often...)
Event log: No suspicious entry that I can see.

**Question**

What is the likely cause of such problem?

Comment: Try [the procedure I have listed here](http://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness) and report back to us... :)

Comment: You should also specify what applications you are running. A hijackthis log will work.

Comment: What kind of Hard drives on on this configuration?

Comment: To rule out a startup program or non Windows Service see this post...http://superuser.com/questions/336199/everything-running-super-slow-in-windows-7-on-my-dell-laptop/336211#336211

Comment: @Wijsman I'll try.

Comment: It was too much a hassle and I have a complete reinstall of windows. curiously it worked. Thanks all for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is your antivirus's real time scanning feature, if you have it enabled.  Try disabling it and seeing if there is an improvement.  You might have more disk access going on in the background than you realize, esp. if you consider Windows Search indexing and background services.  All this must "go through" your real-time antivirus engine if you are using such a program, and it could cause disk access to stall if it needs to "catch up."  If there is an improvement after disabling your antivirus, try another antivirus program.

Do you subscribe to a backup service that might be scanning files in the background (Mozy, etc.)?  This could also cause this issue.

If you have Nero, the PxHelper.sys service might cause issues.  Try uninstalling Nero and/or your current CD/DVD burning software and see if you experience improvement.

Also make sure you have the latest BIOS installed.