# Random PC stuttering

Tags: windows-7, performance, freeze

Okay, my PC stutters too much and it's driving me crazy. Here is more detailed information:

**Stuttering**: A temporary lag, freeze for a couple of milliseconds, the highest was 3 seconds. At this state, the audio goes "bzzzz", the mouse does not move, and I can't do anything. After that, my performance manager records an unusual CPU usage spike, depending on the stutter duration; usually around 60-80 percent.

**Frequency**: around 2-4 times per minute

**Spec**: MSI 890GXM-G65, Athlon II X4 635, Corsair H60, AMD HD6850, 2x2GB DDR3 1600, Intel SSD 330 120GB, Seagate LP 2TB HDD, 400-Watt Corsair 80plus, TPLINK USB wifi adapter, Windows 7 64bit (latest update)

**Experiments I've tried so far that haven't worked**:

1. Closed all visible programs
2. Made sure there was no virus on my PC
3. Ran HD Bench, no bad sectors found, both were in healthy condition, tried connecting only SSD/HDD
4. Ran memory diag, found no problems, tried swapping position
5. Ran speedfan, all hardware was operating in normal temperature ranges
6. Searched for any articles regarding this, so many solutions but none seem to work
7. Updated my drivers.

**Random lead**: Symptoms are not as bad at around 5 hours after powering up my PC, they get worse when my PC runs for a minimum of one day nonstop. At the time of writing this, my PC has been running for 4 days nonstop.

Comment: Athlon may overheat.. dont force it 4 days straight. And do some prime95

Comment: I don't understand, the temperature was always stable and below 30, I can't consider that an overheat

Comment: There is no problem of using a computer in extended hours, what matter is the cooling system, and PSU. I use the computer in normal basis, whether it is idle or high load, the stuttering problem remain the same. And I already stated that even if I turned off my machine, let it cooled down, turn it on again, after 2-3 hours, the stutter comes back, even at 24 degree celcius

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or at least quite similar to) [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/336790/random-short-freezes-in-windows-7?rq=1).

Comment: Nope, that one caused by HDD, mine isn't. I tried everything HDD related issue that might caused this but no, HDD is not the cause in my case.

Comment: So I take it you've read the answer to that question and also ruled out your anti-virus software, Windows indexing your files, other services, and Nero etc.? (By the way, please look at the "help" when commenting; you can notify other commenters by using "@" in front of their name.)

Comment: @aaamos yeah, did those, none works though. Turned off all of my installed program services, only windows services running, still didnt't work. I know its hard for other people to diagnose a problem in someone else PC, 'cos I had that experience. I'll try format my PC, and install program by program after I make sure that program doesn't cause the stutter. I'll let you know when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled windows 2 times until, got several bsod, mostly from atikmpag.sys, my current driver is 12.4 catalyst, upgrade to 12.6 result in VERY noticeable stutter decrease, but not 100%. Revert to old 11.11 eliminate the stutter completely.

For your information people, this is the case of my stutter, the graphic driver. If you have similar spec as mine, maybe this help. :)