# Windows 7 Stucks or freeze after login

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I have windows 7 Pro x64 I have put it on hibernate and since that time it freezes when I log, it works in Safe mode but from time to time the CPU usage goes very high then goes back to normal
I tried Startup Repair but it didn't detect and problem.

I have disabled many startup Apps and some services (Which they are not related to system) but the same problem continued

Any one knows what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Also, I might recommend going into safe mode and running a virus scan, I like "Hitman Pro" http://www.surfright.nl/en for it's quickness. "Malwarebytes" http://www.malwarebytes.org/ for it's thoroughness and for the tough cases "Combo Fix" http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/anti-virus/combofix just make sure you read EVERY prompt in combo fix because it CAN do damage (hasn't happened to me yet, but i've heard horror stories). Hitman Pro is a web-based A/V with a free 30 day trial, therefore, for it to work you must be connected to the internet.

EDIT: It also might be helpful to know if anything has changed since the last good boot. Software/Hardware etc.

Answer (score 0):

Disable all startup items and Non Microsoft Services in msconfig, then reboot, does it still freeze?

[See my Clean Boot troubleshooting post](https://superuser.com/questions/336199/everything-running-super-slow-in-windows-7-on-my-dell-laptop/336211#336211)