# What is causing random hard freezes on my system? Kaspersky?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, kaspersky

The last few weeks I experienced a new strange behavior of my computer. Sometimes Windows 7 just freezes with no real reason at all. While listening to music for example the playback hangs and you can hear a very nasty sound. Neither mouse nor keyboard input is handled and everything is just stuck. Using Ubuntu this does not happen, so I think it is just a matter of driver issues or a Windows 7 bug.

Furthermore I am really suspicious about Kaspersky (Internet Security 11) and so I let it perform a complete virus scan while no other app is running. At about 50% it happened again and I needed to restart the computer by holding the power button the bad way...

A really weird thing is that playing Skyrim this happened once, however music playback did not stop. Only the framerate dropped to 0 and sometimes for a few seconds I am able to move. Therefore I am really confused as furthermore no bluescreen pops up.

Memtest told me that everything seems to be alright...

Can anyone explain me which data you need about my hardware and software (and which tools tools to use to gather the informatik) to be able to provide any help on my problem?

Comment: Would you happen to be running Windows off a Crucial SSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Kaspersky to a newer version I had no more issues - this issues probably comes from the fact that I haven't been reinstalling my computer for ages and therefore I presume that Kaspersky encountered some problems while accessing system files or so. This is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Freezing may occur when there is bad physical connection with your hard drive. Please run eventvwr.msc and look for atapi 11 error. Replacing SATA cable will help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect a startup program is causing it [see my post here](https://superuser.com/questions/336199/everything-running-super-slow-in-windows-7-on-my-dell-laptop/336211#336211)

For more advanced Freeze troubleshooting [see this](https://superuser.com/questions/205298/how-do-i-troubleshoot-a-windows-7-freeze-or-slowness/205307#205307)

Comment: I had a look at your second link, however how can I use the xperf tool when my system does not stop hanging?

Comment: You are right it has to run long enough to fire off xperf, did you try my first link?

Comment: Why should I care about startup applications, as the system is running fine at startup. Furthermore, I had no problems in the last 5 hours! However, due to Murphy's law, it will hang in the next minutes ;) Any other idea how to analyze the system?

Comment: Because startup applications continue to run in the background and one of them may be the cause. A clean boot is the first thing I do when troubleshooting this type of problem. Eliminate 3rd party software and services that are loading at startup. You came here for help and that is what I am trying to do, but you can do as you wish. Similar suggestion here....http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331796/en-us

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic: Since you and I have no idea what is causing this freeze, the best thing to do is to eliminate the easy factors and not to assume. This is why we start with startup processes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CrystalDiskInfo to check whether your hard drive is fine?
I experienced similar symptoms when my hard drive began to crash.
HP's BIOS has a hard drive test built in. If you are using HP then give it a try

Answer (score 0):

2014-Aug-02: Two separate Windows 7 systems started freezing / hanging, after 30 seconds to 1 minute after rebooting. If I hesitated after rebooting, I would not be able to log in -- in fact, the user accounts icons would all disappear from the screen. If I didn't hesitate and logged in immediately after rebooting, after 30 seconds to 1 minute, the system would freeze / hang. To clarify "freeze / hang", the mouse was still responding to movement but I was unable to click the Start Orb or any other item on the desktop. If I previously had a window open, I could move it but not close or interact with it in any other way.

Long story short, I followed [Microsoft's recommended approach to Run Selective Startup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/run-selective-startup-system-configuration#1TC=windows-7) and, through a process of elimination, discovered **the ROOT CAUSE to be Kaspersky (KIS) 2014**. Once I removed it from my computers, the issues went away and the system resumed working 100% to expectations.

I have since been forced to completely uninstall KIS 2014, from all impacted production systems. I am hopeful that Kaspersky has already begun working to identify this glitch and will produce a repair soon.