# System hangs when turned on after several hours of being off

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze

Starting a while ago, my computer began hanging indefinitely a few minutes after showing the login screen. This only happens after the computer has been off for a few hours.

Normally, after restarting the computer, it will work fine after that, but it's quite often that it'll happen a second time in a row, though it rarely happens a third time. This also happens when waking the computer from sleep mode (after sleeping for a few hours). Everything works fine in safe mode, so I've begun to believe that it's a driver problem, but I'm unsure how to go about fixing the problem. Because this problem only occurs after hours of being turned off, it's tedious to diagnose. Doing a [clean boot](https://superuser.com/a/336211/94046) (disabling programs and non-Microsoft services) does not solve the problem.

#### What I've tried

- Booting up with `Boot Logging` turned on. [Output](http://pastie.org/pastes/2945884/text?key=gs0v9vakcpdkb1gr8ue0gg)
- Doesn't hang while in `safe mode`
- Doesn't hang while in `safe mode with networking`
- When I unplugged the computer and moved it somewhere else, it stopped hanging for a few days, but the behavior has returned.

#### Specs

- Operating System: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- Processor: Intel Core i7 CPU
- Video card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260 (driver version [285.62](http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7-winvista-64bit-285.62-whql-driver.html))

Comment: Does this happen in safe mode? Is the CPU high, or memory climbing before it occurs?

Comment: It works fine in safe mode, but I'm unable to notice any CPU changes because it usually happens while I'm logging in and loading the desktop because I try to enter my password quickly in order to use the computer faster.

Comment: Can you create another user and try logging in from there?

Comment: Well, it still freezes at the login screen if I take too long to enter my password (entering my password doesn't help either way), so I don't see how a new user would help.

Comment: in safe mood use msconfig to swap to a diagnostic startup. do these issue happen then>

Comment: No, the issue does not occur. EDIT: But after restarting from the diagnostic boot into a regular boot, it froze before reaching the login screen.

Comment: Great. So it is one of the processes that loads. Go into msconfig, and just disable likely candiates (or edit your question with the possibilities).

Comment: I've already booted without any programs, I call it a clean boot in the question.