# Getting 0xc00000e windows 7 "Boot device inaccessible" after random crashes

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, ssd, crash

I've been having some weird random crashes that I can't seem to locate, and I'm unsure if it's windows or hardware related.

It's a brand new computer and very powerful. I've run into a couple of these random crashes, now I don't know what causes them, as it happens during the night, when I'm sleeping. When I wake up, all I see is a boot manager screen that says Exception: 0xc00000e "Boot device inaccessible". A simple restart doesn't fix the problem - it seems to struggle locating my primary hdd - but a complete shutdown works, it'll just fly straight into windows again.

The event viewer doesn't tell me much.
The most reason incident just gives me this:
"The previous system shutdown at 08:55:44 on ‎11-‎12-‎2011 was unexpected."
And also a kernel power event:
The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.

and I can see only two application event entries around that time at 8.47 (about 8 minutes prior to the crash):

The Windows Modules Installer service entered the running state.

The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state.

Can anyone tell me anything about this, or direct me to a forum or something that might know what's wrong? I can supply the extra details of the events too if needed. The hdd is an SSD - could that have anything to do with it? I ran a few diagnostics and memory and hdd should be okay - at least the diagnostics report is clean. Is it a faulty drive?

Comment: Do you happen to have a dual-boot machine? This error returns a lot concerning dual-boot machines.

Comment: Also, there are a lot more log files that might return something useful. They are located in the same screen where you looked for the application events.

Comment: No dual-boot, and I basically narrowed down the events to what I found to be relevant - the rest all concern the startup, and processes/services being started and stuff like that. None indicate cause at all :/

Comment: Alright. Then I can't help you any further, sorry.

Comment: @Dynde Is it set to sleep or hibernate, we need to know if this is happening when it wakes from sleep or hibernate.

Comment: @Moab it's not - it's on during the entire night, every night. This is an occasional and pretty random thing - timing wise too, it can be 3 am or 5 am, and it doesn't seem to have a time where you'd think some scheduled service or application would run.

Comment: @Dynde Still need to know if the PC is set to sleep or hibernate?

Comment: @Moab I'm sorry, I guess I was unclear, no, as I keep it on during the entire night, it's not set to sleep or hibernate at any time.

Comment: @Dynde All I can suggest is to update all your drivers, if it continues to bsod then run it in a clean boot state a few days to see if the bsod stops, if it does then it is a 3rd party software or Service causing the bsod....http://superuser.com/questions/336199/everything-running-super-slow-in-windows-7-on-my-dell-laptop/336211#336211

Comment: @Moab well, the trouble is, it can run perfectly fine for days, even over a week, then suddenly it happens again. I'm starting to think it might be a faulty drive or maybe ram

Comment: You can stress test the ram by running this program for 24hours...http://www.memtest.org/

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's an SSD has no bearing on this.  My first reaction was that you have a bad HD/SSD, but you mentioned that full restarts work.  So, my suggestions are:

1. Upgrade to latest SSD firmware
2. Upgrade to latest BIOS/UEFI firmware
3. Install all Windows patches
4. Test for bad SSD with manufacturer toolkit or 3rd party toolkit