# Windows 7 Screen/Colour Freeze

Tags: windows-7, freeze, boot

This question might be questioned/answered before, but as I have some specific issues...

Since one month I have a laptop (see details below). It worked perfectly fine until last week, when it started to "crash" or "freeze" on startup (startup = during the actual windows startup / right after the login screen / right after logging in and waiting for windows to load the desktop etc / a minute after startup, right when one want to start working).

The freeze is something I never saw before: it's either an actual freeze, where the computer stops responding, or the screen changes color; either one "random" color (blue, pink, orange) or "random" horizontal stripes the screen.
I had to press the power button several seconds to force a shutdown, whereafter I can successfully start in safe mode. (This post is written in safe mode, actually) Occasionally, after several tries, the computer succeeds in starting up, and once some processes (like playing music or a movie), the computer behaves normally.
System Recovery can't find anything.

Has this something to do with CPU (as the freeze is not constantly on the same moment), a (new) driver? something different?

Also, I tried the method described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/336199/everything-running-super-slow-in-windows-7-on-my-dell-laptop/336211#336211) (a "clean boot") made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Freezing or crashing in this manner could be caused by many different problems.

My first thought is that it may be a driver issue.  Specifically your video (graphics) driver.  Try reinstalling your video driver.  Head to your laptop's manufactures website if it has onboard graphics.  If not the AMD or nvidia sites will have the drivers you need.